# Cutscene system ruled just by time?

Tags: scripting

This is my first time I need to create a cutscene system. I have read a lot on the web about different ways to accomplish this task and have mixed them with my own ideas. Now, it is implementation time, but I need some info from other people with more experience than me in this field. Here we go:

1) Some years ago, I implemented a system that actions could be queued in a serial/parallel way, building a tree of actions that when executed created the final result. This can be sure used as the cutscene system director, but, wouldn't it be so much simple to just have a timeline with actions ran at a certain time? An example:

- playMp3(0, "Song.mp3)
- createObject(0, "Ogre", "Ogre1")
- moveObject(1, "Ogre1", Vector3(100,100,1))

This way everything would be really simple to script. Serial actions are supported buy spreading them correctly in time and parallel actions just need to have shared time ranges.

One problem I have seen is that an action like Sync() (This just waits for all actions to finish before start the other that come afterwards) can't be used because we're using absolute time to trigger our actions. Anyway, a solution could be to have our actions layered based on last "sync()". I mean something like this:

- playMp3(0, "Song.mp3)
- createObject(0, "Ogre", "Ogre1")
- moveObject(1, "Ogre1", Vector3(100,100,1))
- sync()
- moveObject(0,....);
- createObject(1,....);

As you may notice, times after sync() starts again from 0, so, when a sync() is ran, and it determines all previous actions from last sync() are finished, timeLine elapsed time would be 0 again. This can be seen as Little cutscene action groups.

2) The previous explanation needs all actions to be added at the beginning of the cutscene playing. Is this how it usually is done? Or do you usually add actions to the timeline as they are needed?

Well, I could be wrong here, but I think this could be a nice & simple way to lay the actions for a cutscene. What do you think?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One format that I've used is to create a list-of-lists type of structure. The outer list has "time offsets" (keyframe values); the main timer keeps looking until (now >= next), then fires all the events keyed to that frame. (I also put a boolean on the keyframe for "when they press the joystick button, skip forwards to the next frame with this mark")

Comment: Yes, this is another option to solve the sync problem I exposed. Anyway the main reason for the question was to know if anyone was using a system like this for the cutscenes. It seems you do, so, I could be on the right path :). Thanks for the answer

Comment: My last large-scale project actually just used Flash timelines, so YMMV. The problem with `sync` (in my book) is that you have to have a control thread that "hangs" at that line until the other threads catch up… and, depending on your platform, that can be a real pain to work with. (Stackless Python is supposed to be good for that, but I haven't played with it, myself. I use Lispy homebrew languages or Lua for such things.)

Comment: Would you mind reading the last two comments I made to Aleks post? I'm  really interested how lua could avoid the "lota actions" problem. Thanks a lot for all the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a few of these systems. I'll tell you what I like to use I hope this will answer your questions.

One of the first cutscenes system I did used LISP dialect because it is just couple of hours work to get a parser working. It used to be something like...

```
(play "song1.mp3")
(set "ogre1" (create "ogre"))
(moveTo "ogre1" '(100, 100, 100))
(wait 1)
```

I created something like virtual machine (VM) that was processing my scripts. The VM didn't use separate thread instead it had update function that was executing X amount of instructions or until it hits some synchronization instruction like wait for 1 sec.

At that time this system had to work on J2ME device which didn't have XML parser and XML parser was too much code to add. These days I'm using XML for everything except sounds and textures.

These days I'm using keyframe systems as BRPocock suggested. The problem is that this will be harder to manage without proper tools. If you using already some 3D software for your models I'll suggest you to investigate the option to use that product. I use Blender for cutscenes for personal projects since it's free at my work place we use Maya and 3ds Max, but the idea is the same. I export to COLLADA and then I have my animation tracks with keyframes. The problem is that COLLADA format is not the simplest it is made to be flexible and require decent amount of work to extract what you need from it.

The problem you will have with your format is to describe the interpolation so you want to move the ogre from one position to another... how long is this going to take? The advantage of keyframe system is that you can specify the position of the ogre in time... but scripting for such system without a tool will be difficult. Still here is a simple suggestion for format:

```
(play 'song1.mp3')
(entity 'ogre'
    (position (
        0 (100 100 100)
        2 (100 200 100)
        5 (100 300 100)
        7 (100 300 400)
        8 (100 300 500))
    (mood (
        0 'happy'
        7 'angry'))
    (... more tracks for that entity if you need ...))
(entity 'human'
    (position (.....)))
```

Now with format like this you can see at what time where the ogre has to be. So if you have time 1.5 sec in the cutscene you can interpolate between the keyframes with time 0 and 2 sec. Where mood can be something you don't interpolate just swich when the right tome comes. I think this format is going to be more flexible and will solve your sync issues but I wouldn't suggest you writing it by hand without tools for big scripts. If your cutscenes are going to be just few sec with a few entities then it may be good for your.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have all the cutscene regenerated in a 3D package? I have failed to explain the context of my game to let you understand what I really need. My game is 2D and the cutscene system won't need too much bells and whistles. I will be happy just with things like Instantiate object at position, Remove object at position, MoveLeft/Right/Up/Down, Stop, Say, PlayAnimation, etc... This is why I just was thinking in just a time line with actions. Anyway, you both helped a lot understand several problems with my system. Continue in next comment....

Comment: I think I don't really need the keyframe system. My idea was just to have a Director (That owns the timeline) and I will add actions as I exposed previously. This actions could be requested to be added from native C++ or lua script. One of the downsides to this system is that I need to have a bunch of atomic actions (classes). One to create an object, another to move object from here to here and so on. Is there anyway to avoid this? Perhaps this could be accomplished with something like lua and coroutines? Another thing I'm doubting about is to add actions to a director or on the object.

Comment: Essentially, it's about the same thing, inverted: attributes on objects that describe them over time, or attributes at points in time that describe the state of the (screen, world) there. Keeping in mind, a "cutscene" is really just an edge case on any scriptable event, so you may as well use this for "in-world" events as well. ... As far as OOP modeling, I would tend to say you'd have one class per visual object type, maybe a timeline/director, and perhaps an existing one for mixing sounds (shared with the game runtime)?

Comment: And, FWIW Aleks, there's a really clever notion for writing embedded VM's that work like that based on the old "threaded" code compilers in the 60's (nothing to do with threads as in processes) … you basically compile your code down to a series of subroutine calls (e.g. `li 0, SONG_ID_FOO; jsr PLAY_SONG`) that each end with the equivalent of a `yield` (check time slot overrun) or explicitly "deschedule" the script until time *n* elapses.

Comment: Thanks for the comments really instructive.